# Can we have short cut to create link to jira tasks urls in confluence

Tags: confluence

Can we have any automated way to get the jira task urls link when we paste the same on confluence automatically like RT urls.?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not understood your question, but this is always working:

- Have your JIRA and Confluence connected.
- Copy an url of the JIRA task from JIRA.
- Paste it into a Confluence page.
- The link will be immediately replaced with JIRA-link:
  [image: JIRA link pasted in the editor of Confluence page]
- On page save, JIRA link will be added to links section of the page:
  [image: JIRA link from Confluence when you save the page]

Are you sure your JIRA and Confluence are linked and you — as a user — authorized them to access each other?

### If you want to search, not to paste the link

After reading the header of the ticket, I realized that the question might be about search for JIRA-issue from Confluence, not about pasting it from clipboard.
The solution is then to use the "JIRA" macro. It works like this (I am describing the "keyboard-only" solution which I prefer and since you've asked about the shortcut):

- Once again: note that your JIRA and Confluence have to be linked.
- Type `{` (the macro-popup will open), then type `jira` and select JIRA macro (by pressing `Enter`).
  [image: Select JIRA macro from keyboard]
- "Insert JIRA Issue/Filter" window will pop up.
- Type in your JIRA issue number and press `Enter`.
- Wait for the search to complete.
- Press `Ctrl + Enter` (or click on "Insert" button).

This link may also be helpful — https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Auto-link-JIRA-key-in-Confluence/qaq-p/120702.